# Can I use Symbian code to Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Is it possible to convert Symbian code into Blackberry?
if possible tell me the procedure

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use c++ code in j2me. but, you can write a symbian application that listen a port. then you can connect to that port in j2me. so you can pass some task from j2me to symbian. I didnt try it, but I think this is possible.